# How to start the app Docker without opening Docker Desktop on MacOS?

Tags: docker, docker-cli

To be able to run `docker-compose`, I need to have docker desktop running, otherwise I'll get connection refused errors.

Is there a way I can start docker WITHOUT starting the desktop app to be able to then run what needs to be run?

Comment: Please say *why* you don't want to start the desktop app. Thank you.

Comment: I don't want to start the desktop app because I don't need it for the work I do. I never needed it when I worked on Linux and I don't see the need now.